# Creating a multi touch program

Tags: java, eclipse, mt4j

I need to create a multi touch program. I have already install `MT4J` in eclipse but I am unawared of the example that MT4J give. Here are my code:

```
jbtn2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) 
      {
          Sound1.Sound5.play();
      }
});
```

How to modify my mouselistener so that I can make it into a multi touch program.

Comment: I think the point is you don't. I imagine they have there own components and listeners you need to register with

Answer (score 0):

Assuming jbtn2 is a MTImageButton you can add a GestureListener and listen for the event "TapEvent". You want to do something like

```
    button.addGestureListener(TapProcessor.class, new IGestureEventListener() {
        public boolean processGestureEvent(MTGestureEvent ge) {
            TapEvent te = (TapEvent)ge;
            if (te.isTapped()){
                //Code to run when the button is tapped. A MT Event.
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This will allow you to create buttons that accept touches in MT4j, if you want them to also be usable with the mouse you need to add a mouse click listener.

Comment: I gt this error. The method addGestureListener(Class<TapProcessor>, new IGestureEventListener(){}) is undefined for the type JButton